# Animate UIImageView from a subview to parent view

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

I'm working on a project allowing users play chess. I have a parent view which represents a board, each square is added to the board as a subview. Chess piece is an UIImageView and is added to a square as a subview.

```
occupyingPieceImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size))
    self.addSubview(occupyingPieceImageView)
```

To animate a chess move I want to change the position of the piece from one square to an other, I understand that means changing the UIImageView's frame but I don't know how, the frame is only within it's parent view (square). This doesn't work:

```
func move(destSquare: Square){
    var imgView = self.occupyingPieceImageView
    var thisPiece = self.piece
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: {
        self.clearPiece()
        imgView.frame = destSquare.frame
    })
    destSquare.setPiece(thisPiece)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding your pieces to the board itself rather than to squares.  This architecture would allow you to animate any movement, including even placing a piece on the line between two squares.

Comment: I'm considering doing that too but for that I'll need to change the design. Is there any other option.

Comment: What you can do is to set clipsToBounds on all squares to false. Then, you can animate movement using frames that have origin outside the view (e.g. (-100, -100, 50, 50) ) . After animation ends, in completion block, you can recompute coordinates for the new square and do removeFromSuperView and instantly addSubview on a new square. This would be really inefficient, but should work.